# How to get replication agents programatically in AEM?

Tags: java, replication, aem

Is there a way to get author replication agents other than using a Sling query?

Comment: Did u tried any way?

Comment: Subodh, check Dawid's answer, it's much better way to get replication agents.

Comment: Then accept it and enjoy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`AgentManager`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/AgentManager.html) class tp solve your problem

The full AEM replication API is defined [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/replication/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks Dawid, that was what I were looking for !

Comment: Both links are broken!

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Dawid .

A quick(dirty ?) way can be to use the REST url [0] to get a list of all replication agents .

[0]    `<scheme>://<host>:<port>/etc/replication/agents.author.-1.json`